# Facebook Graph Api Bad Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making this request to the graph api and awlays getting a `Bad Request` response from Facebook. I changed it million times already, no luck. Maybe I have read something wrong in the documentation...

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("access_token", authToken);
fd.append("source", blob);
fd.append("message", message);

try {

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" + authToken,
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success " + data);

            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (shr, status, data) {
            console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);

            deferred.reject(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log("Ajax Complete");
        }
    });

} catch (e) {
    alert('error in ajax request ');
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you’re not using the JS SDK for this …?

Comment: The plugin doesn't work with my version of cordova...and the normal JS SDK doesn't log in for some reason... ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to upload a base64 encoded photo directly to facebook using phonegap:

```
function postImage(fileURI, message) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var win = function (r) {

        deferred.resolve(r);
    }

    var fail = function (error) {

        deferred.reject(error);
    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = 'name_of_photo_' + Math.round((+(new Date()) + Math.random()));
    options.mimeType = "image/jpg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.access_token = "your facebook access token ;)";
    params.message = message;
    params.no_story = false;

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURI, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/photos", win, fail, options);

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

With the file-transfer plugin. Add like this: `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer`